# Spanning Set Of $V$ After Linear Transformation Will Span $U$

Tags: linear-algebra

let there be a Linear Transformation $T:V \rightarrow U$ and $B={v_1,...,v_n}$ a spanning set of $V$, so $C=T(v_1),...,T(v_n)$ will span $U$.
Is it right because:
1. there is only one linear transformation from the basis of to $V$ to elements of $U$ 

2. the linear transformation preserve linear combinations?

Comment: Is $T$ surjective?

Comment: $V,W$ are from the same dimension

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit subtle. Your reason $1$ is not entirely true: there can be more than one linear transformations from a basis to another basis (consider the case $V=W$: any invertible linear transform maps a basis to a )Let $n_1$ be the dimension of $V$ and $n_2$ be the dimension of $W$. Take $n=max(n_1,n_2)$. Now you can choose $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$ and $\{w_1,\cdots,w_n\}$ such that each is a spanning set, and just define $T$ to take $v_i$ to $w_i$ and extend linearly.

It's not true for general $T$ thogh: Consider the case $V=W$ and $T=0$.

Comment: I am referring to Proposition 8.3 http://subsite.icu.ac.jp/people/hsuzuki/science/class/linear2/image/lecture8.pdf

Comment: @gbox: Prop $$8.3 is a little different from your condition $1$. If you fix two basis, yes the map $T$ is unique.

Comment: I need just one basis and fixed scalars so T will be unique

Comment: @gbox: yes. you have to make "two sets of choices"

Comment: I think that I have a problem with the notion of "A linear transformation from V to W is determined by where it sends any spanning set of V"

Comment: @gbox: Let $T$ be determined on a spanning set. Take any vector $v \in V$. Then $v=c_1v_1+\cdots+c_nv_n$, and $T(v)=c_1T(v_1)+\cdots+c_nT(v_n)$

Comment: I think I got it, in my question the two vector space are from the same dimension

Answer (score 0):

the answer is yes if $T$ is bijection.otherwise no.for example a projection from a vector space onto a proper subspace doesnt preserve linear independence.